# Server side language for an Ajax interface?

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, web-services, server-side

There's a website with an Ajax interface. My goal is to open up the page with Ajax components locally, in a browser, to let the Ajax interface fetch data (in a text file) from my local server. What is a good server-side language for this? i.e. having a competent library for Ajax interfaces. I want something lightweight so Java is kind of out of the question.

I'm currently thinking PHP, NodeJS or Python. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NodeJS is great for this. It has its own `http` module to make requests as well as tons and tons of user-created libraries to help or provide additional info. The `http` module will give a response that you can easily pipe to a file how you wish. Plus, if you already know Javascript, learning Node is relatively easy.